# What does "there's no way around" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, colloquial-language

Excerpt from *Game Of Thrones*, season 7, the unexpected, secret meeting of Lannister brothers: Tyrion and Jaime Lannister.

> Tyrion: *Danaerys will win this war, you are (referring to Jaime) a military man, you must know **there's no way around***

What do the words in bold mean?

Comment: I edited because I saw you were off-line. If you dislike the edit you can roll it back. As to the question: Did you check in a dictionary? Can you not guess at its meaning?

Comment: When it is a title, it is ok not to capitalize the ''Of'' right?, other than that I've got no problem with the editing. Whereas, In regards to looking up to a dictionary, yes I did it, but no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"There's no way around (it)" means that *there is no solution to avoid a particular outcome.*  Examples.

> If you want to get good at English, you have to memorize a lot of idioms.  **There's no way around it**.
>
> At some point I'm going to have to meet with my fiance's parents.  They seem to hate me, but there's **no way around it**.